# How do I focus a combo box inside a grid panel?

Tags: combobox, extjs4, gridpanel

I've searched high and low and can't find this and all of my methods do not work.

Basically, here is what I have. I have a Grid Panel (using `ExtJS 4`) that contains many rows. Each row has a column that contains a combo box.

Now, I have a "Add" button that when clicked, adds a new model and inserts it into the store. Works great. However, the user has to use the mouse and click the combo box inside the newly inserted row to begin typing. Our app is heavily focused on the keyboard and the mouse is discouraged (being a data entry app).

I am able to select the first row with a:

```
grid.view.getSelectionModel().select(newRow);
```

However, the combo box inside isn't focused.

How can I solve this?

Thanks.

**EDIT**

I've tried to post my source code here on SO but it keeps timing out so here is a `gist` of my code:

https://gist.github.com/1089782

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't check it for for comboboxes but it worked for textfields:

1. Firstly assign id to celledit plugin:

   `plugins: [
      Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing', {
         clicksToEdit: 1,
         id: 'my_plugin'
      })
   ]`
2. And then, provided `newRow` is newly inserted model and column with comboboxes has index == 1, you can use:
   `grid.getPlugin('my_plugin').startEditByPosition({row: newRow.index, column: 1});`

Comment: Actually, I already solved this using a similar method.  I just didn't understand that it was in the CellEditing plugin.  Once I made that discovery, it was easy!  Which is frustrating because I spent so much time just looking in the wrong place.  That's what I get for being a ExtJS newbie.  But I awarded you the bounty anyway because you are the only one here that actually had a correct answer.  :-)  thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. You have to save reference to that combobox somewhere. For example in record you might have     field 'combo' and it will reference to combobox.
2. After selection you have to do: **record.combo.fosus();** and that is all.

Comment: I can't seem to find where to put the reference?  I have a `var` named 'timeEntryDetailsEditorGrid` which contains the combobox `cbSiteActivities`.  But calling focus on that after a new row is inserted does nothing

Comment: Put that code on afterrender event. combo.on('afterrender', function(combo) {combo.focus()})

Comment: Thanks.  I've tried that.  The afterrender event only works when I actually click the combo box.

Comment: I'vw glanced to you source code and noitced that you have "autoRender : false". Maybe that's why that event is not firing...

Comment: Thanks.  Tried changing it to true and it doesn't render at all when I click it.

Comment: I have tried to load up your codes in github but turns out it doesn't has all the code included. This is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chaoszcat/jPLrt/) that you might be interest in. Similar to what we have in the [core example](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.2a/examples/grid/cell-editing.html) thou.